# What are the security implications of installing an iPhone configuration profile?

Tags: appsec, mobile, ios, iphone, configuration

What are the security risks of installing a "configuration profile" on iOS from `www.vshare.com`? I don't know what a configuration profile is or what it does. They are found in Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management.

Also, what are the security risks of trusting an "enterprise app", which is found in the same place in settings?

Comment: Well, one major security risk is "I don't know what a configuration profile is or what it does."

Comment: I'd suggest removing the link and keeping this question more broad.

Answer (score 1):

These configuration profiles can be used to install certificates on your phone. This let's the company then MITM your traffic and sniff all of your HTTPS connections. This comes down to whether you trust this company to see all your traffic and keep their private key safe so others can't pretend to be them.

As for "trusting" an app, installing any software you don't know about or inherently trust is probably a bad idea.

Comment: You would still have to visit a particular site that presents a bogus certificate, wouldn't you? Just because you have a new fraudulent root certificate doesn't mean everyone uses it. That site says it contains a 'web clip'. And doesn't iOS partition apps to prevent them from reading each other's data?